# Keyframe no css para efeito de background

Tags: html, css, animação

Olá, tudo bem?
Eu tentei fazer uma mudança de background usando keyframe, porém as imagens quando mudam piscam na primeira vez, como se estivesse carregando. Isso é normal ou fiz algo errado?
Aqui está a página no github pages. Estou tentando fazer para celulares primeiro e depois para desktop.

https://frazaovitor.github.io/Projeto-AVIX/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>AVIX CAMISARIA</title>
</head>
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>Desfazendo</h1>
        <img src="img/avixLogo.png" alt="logo avix">
        <h1> Padrões</h1>
    </div>
</header>
<body>
    <div class="carrossel"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.carrossel {
  height: 92vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: background 40s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes background {
  0% {
    background-image: url("../img/background1.jpg");
  }
  25% {
    background-image: url("../img/background2.jpg");
  }
  50% {
    background-image: url("../img/background3.jpg");
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url("../img/background4.jpg");
  }
}
```

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é normal, elas não piscam, na verdade a area esta com fundo branco, a próxima imagem ainda não foi carregada, se você estive-se em uma internet lenta, tipo um 3G lento, talvez nem visse a foto, o que você pode fazer é talvez trocar por `<img>` ou usar um sistema de carrousel "melhor", ou então para ajudar no código que já tem você poderia usar o https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content

Exemplo:

```
<head>
  ...

  <link rel="preload" href="../img/background1.jpg" as="image">
  <link rel="preload" href="../img/background2.jpg" as="image">
  <link rel="preload" href="../img/background3.jpg" as="image">
  <link rel="preload" href="../img/background4.jpg" as="image">
</head>
```

Lembrando que o Firefox não suporta isso, pois houve diversos problemas anteriormente e por enquanto tal recurso está desabilitado no navegador.

Recomendo realmente que use `<img>` ou um sistema de carousel pronto.

Comment: Entendi. Estava pronto pra mudar pra um jquery ou fazer no JS mesmo, mas queria tirar essa dúvida! Obrigado!